# How to map the node identities of my resulting surface mesh generated from Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3 into my starting point sets?

Tags: cgal

thanks for reading this question. My title is basically what I'm trying to achieve.  I did a poisson surface mesh generation using Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3(cgal). I can't figure out how to map the node identities of my resulting surface mesh into my starting point sets?

The output of my poisson surface generation is produced by the following lines:
    CGAL::facets_in_complex_2_to_triangle_mesh(c2t3, output_mesh);
    out << output_mesh;
In my output file, there are some x y z coordinates, followed by a set of 3 integers each line, I think they indicates which nodes form a delaunay triangle. The problem is that the output points do not correspond to my initial point set, since not any x y z value match to any of my original points.  Yet I'm trying to figure out which points are forming a delaunay triangles in my original point set.

Could someone suggest me how can I do this in cgal?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The poisson recontruction algorithm consist in meshing an implicit function that somehow fits you input points. In practice, it means that you input point will no belong to the set of points of the output surface, and won't even lie exactly on triangles of the output surface. However, they should not be too far from the output surface (except if you have some really sparse sampling parts).

What you can do to locate your input points with the output surface is to use the function [`closest_point_and_primitive()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classCGAL_1_1AABB__tree.html#a1b3ac9521fd7257f760deafff3743437) from the AABB-tree class.

Here is an [example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/AABB_tree_2AABB_face_graph_triangle_example_8cpp-example.html) of how to build the tree from a mesh.